# How to prevent a double submit

Tags: reactjs

I have the current code where with a button (OpenModal.jsx) the user open a modal where he can save data in a database, the problem that I have is that if the user is fast enough to click submit twice before the modal close he can save the same data twice (send a double submit).

What is the best way to prevent this?

OpenModal.jsx

```
const OpenModal = () => {
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <button
                className="openModalBtn"
                onClick={() => {
                    setOpenModal(true);
                }}
            >
                Set note
            </button>
            {openModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} />}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Modal.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Modal = ({ closeModal }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        note: "",
    });

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
                {
                    note: data.note,
                }
            );
            response.data.success ? closeModal(false) : null;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const handle = (e) => {
        const getData = { ...data };
        getData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
        setData(getData);
    };

    return (
        <div className="modal">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <form onSubmit={(e) => submit(e)}>
                    <div className="close-content">
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn-close"
                            onClick={() => {
                                closeModal(false);
                            }}
                        >
                            X
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-content">
                        <label>
                            Note:
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                required
                                onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
                                id="note"
                            />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="buttons-form">
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn-cancel"
                            onClick={() => {
                                closeModal(false);
                            }}
                        >
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button className="btn-save" type="submit">
                            Save
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the button while the operation is processing.  You can keep a `disabled` flag in state:

```
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);
```

And use it on the button:

```
<button className="btn-save" type="submit" disabled={isDisabled}>
  Save
</button>
```

Then update that state as needed:

```
const submit = async (e) => {
    setIsDisabled(true); // <--- here
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
            {
                note: data.note,
            }
        );
        setIsDisabled(false); // <--- here
        response.data.success ? closeModal(false) : null;
    } catch (error) {
        setIsDisabled(false); // <--- here
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

For improved UX, you might even replace the button text with a spinner or some other indication that "something is processing" while it's disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an `isLoading` state that you set to `true` when the submit button is clicked and `false` when the request is completed. Then, you can either make the button disabled when that state is `true` or simply don't send the request in the `submit` function if the request is loading:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

const submit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (isLoading) 
    return;

  setIsLoading(true);
  
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`, {
        note: data.note,
      }
    );
    response.data.success ? closeModal(false) : null;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should introduce safety flag, to know when submitting started and when finished, and like that user will not be able to hit it twice because you can set constraints with flag. Do something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    note: "",
});
const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);


 const submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!submitting) {
        setSubmitting(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
                {
                    note: data.note,
                }
            );
            response.data.success ? closeModal(false) : null;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } finally {
          setSubmitting(false);
        }
      }
  };
```